# Access JavaScript variable in CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sass, less

Below is the code for reference. Value for variable 'imgpath' is changed on load. I need to assign this new value for background image of class 'icon1'. 
I know this can be done using JavaScript/jQuery, but I need some way to do update this value in CSS itself.
Can it be possible using Sass/Less or any other way?

```
<html>

<head>
    <style>
    .icon1 {
        background: transparent url("imagepath1/icon1.png") no-repeat center center;
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <a class="icon1"></a>
    <script>
    var imgpath = "imagepath1";
    if (setnewpath)
        imgpath = "imagepath2";
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Thank you for replies but I know how to do it using javascript/jquery. But I need to know whether it is possible using sass/less?

Comment: it is impossible to access javascript variables with css or sass, you could consider running nodeJS.

Answer (score 4):

**You cannot access `Javascript` in `CSS`.**

You can use [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) to set the `css` properties using jQuery.

```
$('.icon1').css('background-image', imgpath + '/icon1.png');
```

**Setting all the properties**

```
$('.icon1').css('background', 'transparent url("' + imgpath + '/icon1.png") no-repeat center center');
```

`css()`:

> Set one or more CSS properties for the set of matched elements.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access javascript from css, but vise versa. See this code:

```
document.getElementByClassName("icon").style.backgroundImage = "url('+imgpath + '/icon1.png')";
```

I would prefer this solution, instead of Tushar's, just as it will work on it's own. You don't need jQuery for such a small task.

Answer (score 0):

I get reference from [**W3cschool**](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_background.asp)

```
document.getElementsByClassName('icon1').background = "transparent url(" +imgpath + "/icon1.png") no-repeat center center";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use model variable as razor,I think it's acceptable:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
    .icon1 { background:transparent url(@Model.imgpath ) no-repeat center center;
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <a class="icon1"></a>
    <script>
      var imgpath = "imagepath1";
      if(setnewpath)
        imgpath = "imagepath2";
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you provide more details on it?

Comment: I assume that you used asp.net mvc,you should define a string type variable (i.e.imagpath) in model,then you can get the value in controller (or calling service in controller ),so you can use razor syntax "@Model.imagpath" to let it work.

Comment: No, there is no .net involve. This is client side only

Comment: Is there any server side to handle it?if pure js,you can define a class for dom in less,use js to modify that.

Comment: Can you please provide any example ?

Comment: document.getElementById("").className = "MyClass"

Comment: Sorry I still think it should be computed the path value in server side.or there are some classes predefined(including different image) but it's not good if there are many images select-able.

Comment: Thing is I'm getting data after page load and then depending on that I decide which path to add for images. Looks like I have to do it through jQuery only.

Answer (score 0):

Lucky for you, stylesheets and rules are actually exposed to the DOM.

One simple way to do it would be to grab a reference to the  element and replace its textContent with completely new CSS source, built in JavaScript. I'm not entirely sure if that will actually work, though. Depends on if the browser bothers to re-parse the new content as new CSS.

A slightly more complicated approach that *should* work, however, is to actually use the StyleSheets Object Model.

You can get the stylesheet with `var sheet = document.styleSheets[0];`

Then get the rule with `var rule = sheet.cssRules[0];`

You can then replace the rule text: `rule.cssText = '.icon1 { background:transparent url("'+imagepath+'") no-repeat center center;';`

Sadly, the API doesn't get more fine-grained that replacing the entire rule text at once.

You can also delete rules and add new ones, rather than altering the text in-place, if you so desire. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSSStyleSheet

Comment: Seems interesting. But as you say, there can be browser restrictions.